# Multiple Object Tracking OpenCV Python, contours keep swapping

Tags: python, opencv

So I am trying to write a program that will tracking 3 contours of the same size and color, while keeping separately identified, but the contours keep jumping from one to another. For example, I have red, green and blue circles on each contour, but contour#1 would flip between red and green and vice-versa. I am sorting the contours by size, but even if I don't, I still run across the same problem. I am running OpenCV 3.2 and python 3.5.

```
if len(cnts) > 2:                                                       
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]     
    for i in range(0,3):                                                
        ((x[i], y[i]), radius[i]) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnts[i])     
        for i in range(0,3):                                            
            M = cv2.moments(cnts[i])                                    
            center[i] = (int(M["m10"]/ M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
        if flag is False:                                               
            for i in range(0,3):                                        
                cup[i]=center[i]                                        
            flag = True                                                 
        else:                                                           
            if radius[i]>10:                                                            
                for i in range(0,3):                                        
                cup[i] = center[closestPoint(cup[i], center)]           
                #for i in range (0,3):                                  
                cv2.circle(frame, (int(cup[i][0]), int(cup[i][1])),     
                       int(radius[i]), color[i],2)                  
                cv2.circle(frame,(cup[i][0],cup[i][1]),5,(0,0,255),-1)
```

Comment: use probabilistic tracking: If the velocity of your objects doesn't "jump" too strong you should be able to track by assuming a constant velocity with normal distributed velocity change => you can assign a probability to each possible ordering/track and after a few frames you might find the right ones.

Comment: I thought about using a particle filter instead of my closestpoint function (basically closest euclidean distance finder) but I could not figure out how to implement it into my script

Comment: Also do you have an idea of how I should sort my contours? If I sort by size then the tracked contours will change if there is any bit of obstruction. I.E. the red contour is always the smallest, so the smallest contour will always track as red. If I do not track by size then everytime the ordering of the contours change by position the tracking flips again. i.e. the circle is always the contour at the bottom.

Comment: can you post a typixal video to give an impression?

Comment: Hopefully this clears things up. I appreciate all the help thus far.  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_S_KdKQtSU&feature=youtu.be)